# Simple email duplicate submission Node.js

Tags: node.js, total.js

I have been working on a simple duplicate email submission, here it is:

```
   var filter = function (o) { // o.email query - already submitted query a@a.com

    return o.email === email; // passing a@a.com or awe@awe.com

   };

  db.one(filter, function(email) { // function not picking up callback

    if (email == null) {  //same - callback returns null 

        error.add('duplicate');
        self.json(error);
        return;

    }

    /....other code .../
});
```

How could I get the result of the callback?

Comment: Documentation: https://github.com/petersirka/nosql

Answer (score 2):

In the node.js world, callbacks have the convention of placing the first parameter as the error (`err`), and the second parameter as the data result (`email`).

```
db.one(filter, function(err, email) {
  console.log(email);
});
```